# PHP site to post data to ASP.net Webservice

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

I've got a site running on php and I need my form to post data to an ASP.Net web service.  All I have from the ASP.Net web service is a url ending in .svc and then I open up the url I get another link that I can click on which ends in .svc?wdsl

This is all pretty new to me so I'm not sure where to begin, any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.svc?wsdl` link will give you the WSDL for the web service (which describes which methods are available and what their parameters are).

Once you have the WSDL, you can construct a [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) with it and call the methods.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Will check the available methods.

Comment: When I loaded up the .svc?wsdl link it loaded an xml document and I'm guessing the <wsdl:operation name="#####"> is the method?

Comment: Thanks, it was correct.  I wasn't given alot of info on methods or how the parameters are to be passed.  I've since figured it out and everything works very well now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET site is exposing a WCF service, and the `?wsdl` url you're seeing (pronounced wis-dul) is a XML file which describes all of the functionality provided by the service and the input/output parameters. See the Wikipedia article on [Web Services Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) for more info.

With the small amount of background info, you can find some examples about consuming a WCF service from PHP (the fact that it's a WCF service shouldn't make any difference btw, so any example of consuming a web service should work):

- http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx
- http://spacebug.com/php-calling-wcf-part-2-html/

Comment: Thanks for the links, will check them both out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've been given a .NET SOAP Web Service to consume.

Check out the PHP docs for consuming/working with SOAP Services:

**[PHP: SOAP - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)** (Paying close attention to SoapClient which is what you'll use to actually construct and call the service)

Answer (score 0):

steven,

you'll need to do a refresher on wsdl and webservices under .net.

there are obviously lots of places to look online but certainly if you google: 'asp.net wcf wsdl webservice' you should get plenty of hits to help you along.

jim